# IndexError: tuple index out of range - Django

Tags: python, django, heroku-postgres

I am getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range` when trying to do a consult to the DB (Heroku postgres):

```
def get_total_per_month(request, year):
    user= User.objects.values("id").filter(username=request.user)    
    query = (        
        f"SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', \"move_date\"), 'MM') AS month_number,"
        f" sum( CASE WHEN \"move_id\" = 1 THEN \"move_value\" WHEN \"move_id\" = 2 THEN -\"move_value\" END ) as total"
        f" FROM move_control WHERE \"user_id\" = {user[0]['id']}"
        f" AND \"move_date\"::text LIKE '{year}%' GROUP BY month_number"
    )
 
    # Retrieve data
    for p in Move.objects.raw(query):
        print(p)
```

When trying to retrieve the data the following error shows:

```
File "C:\Users\LonxfUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've tried this query directly from the database and it works, so maybe I'm missing something. I have looked at the documentation of Django but what I've tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`user[0]['id']` is the only occurrence of tuple indexing in that code.  So `user` must be an empty tuple, which means your filter expression did not match any users.

I'm guessing here, but I think the filter expression is matching on the wrong attribute.  `request.user` is the entire user object, which will not match the username.  Try `request.user.username` instead.

Also, why are you using `.values("id")` in the filter expression?  That restricts the query to return **only** the `id` attribute, so matching on username would be impossible.

Comment: I changed the variables for values that i want in the query (user -> 4, year -> 2021):
 
`query = (        
        f"SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', \"move_date\"), 'MM') AS month_number,"
        f" sum( CASE WHEN \"move_id\" = 1 THEN \"move_value\" WHEN \"move_id\" = 2 THEN -\"move_value\" END ) as total"
        f" FROM move_control WHERE \"user_id\" = 4"
        f" AND \"move_date\"::text LIKE '2021%' GROUP BY month_number"
    )`

But it didn't work, it keeps showing the same `index tuple error`

Comment: The problem is the filter expression, not the sql query.

Comment: But if i remove that part of the code i keep getting the error.

Comment: That updated query does not contain any tuple operations, so I don't see how you could still be getting a tuple error...